# Instagram Business API Rate Limits

Tags: facebook-graph-api, instagram-api

In Facebook documentation there are two types of limits mentioned:-

The Platform rate limit:

**((200* users)/hour)** which is for Business Discover and Hashtag APIs,

and the Instagram Business Use Case rate limiting:

**((4800 * impressions)/day)** which is mentioned to be used for other instagram APIs.

I want to know which one applies to the insights api calls and how to calculate the calls for the Instagram Business Use Case because it's not provided in the dashboard (found only the the platform limit)

Comment: I don’t think insights have _anything whatsoever_ to do with business discovery or hashtag API, so that would fall under “other” then.

Comment: How can i know how many calls i've got? which account's impressions they use to calculate that?